# Обработка нажатия на кнопку в Alert (ReactJS + vkui)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vkontakte-api

Cтолкнулся с проблемой, при открытии Alert меню в моём приложении, я не могу обработать нажатия кнопки в нем.
Сам алерт:

```
openEmail = () => {
        this.setState({ popout : 
            <Alert onClose={this.closePopout}
            actions={[
                {title: 'Отмена', onPress: this.getNick(), style: 'cancel',},
                {title: 'Понятно', onPress: console.log('OK Pressed')},
            ]}>
              <h2>Подтвердите действие</h2>
              <p>Для входа через E-MAIL, почта привязанная к вашему ВК должна совпадать с почтой аккаунта.</p>
            </Alert>
        });
    };
```

При его вызове я вижу в консоли OK Pressed, но я не нажимал ни одну из этих кнопок, так же при нажатии на кнопки я не получаю никакого уведомления!

( Использую React + библиотеку vkui )

Answer (score 0):

Для этого вы можете использовать confirm('текст') который имеет возврат Boolean